# localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect

Tags: java, cassandra, connection

Trying to connect Cassandra with Java via below code and getting localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect error-

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cluster cluster;
        Session session;
        //cluster connects to the address of the node provided.One contact point is required.Good to have multiple
        cluster=Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build();

        session=cluster.connect("ecommerce");
        session.execute("INSERT INTO products (pdt_id, cat_id, pdt_name, pdt_desc, price, shipping) VALUES (002,105, 'Candy 0.9 cu. ft. Washing Machine', 'Capacity of 1 cu. ft.10 different power levels', 64.00, 'Expedited')");
        session.execute("INSERT INTO products (pdt_id, cat_id, pdt_name, pdt_desc, price, shipping) VALUES (003,106, 'Prestige 0.9 cu.cm. Pressure Cooker', 'Capacity: 18 qt.', 70.00, 'Dispatched from warehouse')");

        String pdtid = null, pdtname = null, pdtdesc = null;
        float price = 0;
        ResultSet resultSet=session.execute("select * from products");
        for(Row row:resultSet)
        {
            pdtid = Integer.toString(row.getInt("pdt_id"));
            pdtname = row.getString("pdt_name");
        }
        cluster.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post proper the error message/traceback and the variables value passed in environment.

Comment: Since you are using a Windows machine to run Cassandra, use command netstat -aon to check if any process is listening on default Cassandra port 9042. If some process is listening to port, check the PID in Task Manager's Details tab.

Comment: There are no applications that are particularly listening to 127.0.0.1:9042.

Comment: This means your Cassandra itself is not running. Please share the guide which you are using to setup Cassandra on your windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

The java code syntax looks correct to me.

Please Make sure you have Cassandra is running on your machine and port 9042 open (check firewall). You can check to execute `cqlsh` and see if Cassandra is responding.

I see you are using an outdated version of the driver. You should consider updgrading to 4.x. Here is the complete documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/

Comment: I might have some issue while running cqlsh. I am not getting any error but I am not getting navigated to cqlsh command line. PFB                                                                                                                                   C:\Users\spant2\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\bin>cqlsh [127.0.0.1[9042]]
C:\Users\spant2\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\bin>